# jQuery selecting issue, how to select elements when event occurred?

Tags: jquery

I have several buttons, by clicking on them depending on the state (true or false) stored in database, 0: using ajax changes value in db, 1:appears confirmation modal, if user confirms, then again using ajax value changes.

**HTML:**

```
<span class="1" data-state="{{ $subscribe->newsletter }}" data-type="1"></span>
<span class="2" data-state="{{ $subscribe->send_products }}" data-type="2"></span>
<span class="3" data-state="{{ $subscribe->send_shares}}" data-type="3"></span>
```

**jQuery:**

```
  var confirm_modal = $('#unsubscribe-confirmation');

  $('.1, .2, .3').click(function() {

     var button = $(this);
     var state = $(this).data('state');
     var type = $(this).data('type');

     if ( state == 1 ) {
        confirm_modal.modal();
     } else {
        $.ajax({
           'url': get_base_url_with_ajax_url() + 'subscribe',
           'data': { "state": state, "type" : type },
           'type': 'POST',
           'dataType': 'json',
           success: function(result) {
              button.attr('data-state', '1');
           }
        });
     }
  });
 confirm_modal.find('#confirm').click(function() {
     $.ajax({
        'url': get_base_url_with_ajax_url() + 'subscribe',
        'data': { "state": state, "type": type },
        'type': 'POST',
        'dataType': 'json',
        success: function(result) {
           $(this).attr('data-state', '0');
           confirm_modal.modal('hide');
        }
  });
```

So, in first statement, when changing data-state, selector $(this) is worked. But when appeares modal how can I select elements, which was taken at first: ".sbs-nwlttr, .sbs-evt, .sbs-prod"?

Thanks for attention.

Comment: why don't you make use of your `button` variable that stores `$(this)` already for you...?

Comment: because variable button initialized in if statement, and in event when clicking on modal button, it is undefined

Comment: not sure, but it looks like `confirm_modal.find('#confirm').click(function()` is inside `$('.sbs-nwlttr, .sbs-evt, .sbs-prod').click(function()` and it's not closed (no `}` at the end) - is that intentional?

Comment: i see you just edited your original post transforming the selectors into numbers, but that's not valid markup, so i'd change them back if i was you - more on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors

Comment: it's my mistake, event with modal-clicking is outside of clicking on span-elements

Comment: @lalexa I would recommend using jquery's on function

Answer (score 1):

First of all, though I suspect you only used it for testing, avoid using one digit class names, and ones that start with a number as that's not allowed in css (more details can be found on that in [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)), so rename `class="1"` to `class="one"` for example.

On the other the only problem you have is that your `button` variable is not global, only declared inside one of the functions. Declare it outside, then you can make use of it in the other function too as follows:

```
var button;

$('.one, .two, .three').click(function() {

    button = $(this);
    // ...
}

confirm_modal.find('#confirm').click(function() {

    alert(button.text()); // for example

}
```

I set up a fiddle that demonstrates this (slightly different from the above, but should show the behaviour clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/wz6v306k/